# 6, the magic number

Tags: mathematics

Here's a fun (albeit difficult) one:

Make these equations true using arithmetic operations:

```
1 1 1 = 6
2 2 2 = 6
3 3 3 = 6
4 4 4 = 6
5 5 5 = 6
6 6 6 = 6
7 7 7 = 6
8 8 8 = 6
9 9 9 = 6
```

For example: `6 + 6 - 6 = 6` (I hope I did not spoil some of you :D)

Allowed operators are:

```
+, -, *, /, ! , ^, %
```

Setting parenthesis is also allowed.

The `^` operator is an exception as you are permitted to supply a second argument to it which may be any positive integer or the multiplicative inverse of it.

$x^{1/y}$ is **always** positive and real.

If you find an alternative solution using other operators you may post it but please also provide a solution using only these 7 operators.

---

For those of you who think this was easy, here is a bonus:

```
0 0 0 = 6
```

Comment: Obviously not only -,+,*,/ are allowed. Please tell full list of allowed operations.

Comment: "(x^0 + x^0 + x^0)!" - so you allowed to use additional numbers and ()?

Comment: @klm123 Yes, you are allowed to use additional numbers, but only as second argument to the ``^`` operator

Comment: Then "(x^0 + x^0 + x^0)!" satisfies. What does mean "be more creative"? You need to reformulate it using only objective criteria.

Comment: @klm123 Eliminated that possibility

Comment: I've seen this puzzle before, and I can (almost) guarantee it isn't possible without grouping, though it is possible without exponentiation. I think the operator to remove in this case is the exponentiation, not the parentheses, but that's just my opinion on the matter. Just be prepared to accept "this can't be done" as an answer otherwise.

Comment: Parenthesis? Allowed?

Comment: @kaine Yes, parenthesis are allowed

Comment: @Emrakul I included exponentiation for more possibilities. Surely someone will come up with a solution not using it.

Comment: How about square roots?

Comment: @BitNinja Allowed, I'll add it in a sec

Comment: I have no idea how to do this for 5, 8, or 9. Hints, anyone?

Comment: @Rhymoid 5 is only 1 away from 6...

Comment: @ThreeFx Right. Overlooked that one pretty badly.

Comment: If you're allowing multiplicative inverses of positive integers in exponents, that doesn't add unambiguous terms for potential solutions because it doesn't appear that you've provided a way to choose which root to use.

Comment: @Muqo Well you an choose between squareroot, cuberoot and so on. What is the problem with that?

Comment: @ThreeFx By "choose which root", I mean choosing which result given a particular root.  Every positive integer has two different square roots, three different cube roots, and so on.  For example, if I want to use 8^(1/3), how do I specify which of the one real and two complex results to use in my expression?  Multiple solutions exist for 8 to get 6 using different cube roots.

Comment: @Muqo For the sake of keeping everything nice and clean, we will only consider the positive real roots

Comment: @Emrakul A bit late to reply, but I think that 8s and 9s aren't possible without exponentiation.

Comment: @ThreeFx additional numbers are not allowed in the original/correct version of this puzzle

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1.

> $(1+1+1)! = 6 $

2.

> $2+2+2 = 6$

3.

> $3*3-3 = 6$

4.

> $\left(4-\frac 4 4\right)! = \sqrt 4+\sqrt 4+\sqrt 4=6$

5.

> $5+\frac 5 5 = 6$

6.

> $6*\frac 6 6 = 6 + 6 -6=6$

7.

> $7-\frac 7 7 = 6$

8.

> $\left(\sqrt{8+\frac 8 8}\right)! = 6$

9.

> $\left(\frac{\sqrt{9}\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt 9}\right)! = 6$

Bonus:

> $(0!+0!+0!)! = 6$

Comment: Bonus: (0^0 + 0^0 + 0^0)!

Comment: @c0rp ``0^0`` is NaN. Also, you can only choose a **positive exponent**.

Comment: $0! = 1$, though.

Comment: @BenMillwood Sure but one has to know that in order to be able to use it

Comment: @ThreeFx `0^0` is not always NaN depending on who you ask and what field you're in. It can also be set to `0^0=1`

Comment: "one has to know that in order to be able to use it"? What on earth does that mean?

Comment: for 9, this should also be considered  (9+9)/√9

Comment: 8: 8^1/3+8^1/3+8^1/3

Comment: @marmeladze or just to keep things simply written for above, $\sqrt{\small9\times 9\div 9}!$

Comment: @user477343 that's what already BitNinja did.  √9 × √9 / √9 = √(9×9÷9)

Comment: @marmeladze my point exactly; it is simpler to write it with one radical as opposed to three :)

Answer (score 32):

I insist on using all the digits!

> $(1 + 1^{1234567890} + 1)! = 6$
>
>  $(2 + (2^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 2)!)! = 6$
>
>  $(3 + 3^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 3)! = 6$
>
>  $(4 - (4^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 4)!)! = 6$
>
>  $5 + (5^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 5)! = 6$
>
>  $6 + 6^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 6 = 6$
>
>  $7 - (7^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 7)! = 6$
>
>  $(\sqrt[3]8 + (8^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 8)!)! = 6$
>
>  $(\sqrt{9} + (9^{1234567890}\ \text{mod}\ 9))! = 6$
>
>  $(0! + (0^{1234567890})! + 0!)! = 6$

No, wait!  How about if we take subtraction out and put subfactorial in?  More exclamation points!!!!

> $((!1)! + (!1)! + (!1)!)! = 6$
>
>  $(!2 + !2 + !2)! = 6$
>
>  $!3 + !3 + !3 = 6$
>
>  $(\sqrt{!4} \times 4 \div 4)! = 6$
>
>  $!(\sqrt{!5\ \text{mod}\ 5}) + 5 = 6$
>
>  $!6\ \text{mod}\ 6 \times 6 = 6$
>
>  $!7\ \text{mod}\ 7\ \text{mod}\ 7 = 6$
>
>  $(!8\ \text{mod}\ 8 + \sqrt[3]8)! = 6$
>
>  $\sqrt[3]{!9\ \text{mod}\ 9} \times \sqrt9 = 6$
>
>  $(!0 + !0 + !0)! = 6$

Comment: ????!!!!????!!!!

Comment: @rand al'thor You look like you need some **‽**'s!!  Hold on, is there a **‽** operator, too‽‽  This answer might need revision!!

Answer (score 8):

The bottom five (0 through 4) can all be solved using the same construction:

> `(0!+0!+0!)! = 6`
>      `(1 +1 +1 )! = 6`
>      `(2 +2 /2 )! = 6`
>      `(3 +3 %3 )! = 6`
>      `(4 -4 /4 )! = 6`

For 6 and 7, there are slightly more funky solutions:

> `(6!)%(6!-6)=6`
>      `((7!)/7)%7=6`

(I haven't found an interesting solution for 5, nor any square-root-free solutions for 8 or 9.)

Comment: [Square roots are allowed.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/6-the-magic-number?noredirect=1#comment3860_1963)

Comment: I don't know who edited my answer or why, but I disagree with it. Why it was approved is a mystery to me. The added answer for 9 is incorrect. The answer for 8 uses the double factorial operator (not the same as the factorial of the factorial of its operand), which was not explicitly allowed by OP. To top it off, the markup was broken and would not properly hide the answers.

Answer (score 7):

Here we go.

## 1:

> $(1+1+1)! = 6$
>  This is the only possible one as far as I know.

## 2:

> $2+2+2 = 6$

## 3:

> $3*3-3 = 6$

## 4:

> $4+(4/\sqrt{4}) = 6$

## 5:

> $5+(5/5) = 6$

## 6:

> $6*(6/6) = 6$

## 7:

> $7-(7/7) = 6$

## 8:

> 8 - $\sqrt[4]{8 + 8} = 6$

## 9:

> $(9+9)/\sqrt{9} = 6$

## Bonus - 0:

> $(0! + 0! + 0!)! = 6$

Comment: Nice solutions, I particulary like the one to number 8, definitely worthy of an upvote. :D

Comment: Well, is only if you allow roots, and the solution to #8 requires a "4"

Comment: @HSuke Well, that's just taking square root twice

Answer (score 3):

> 1. $(1+1+1)! = 6 $
>  2. $2+2+2 = 6 $
>  3. $3*3-3 = 6$
>  4. $4^3/4^2+4^{1/2} = 6$
>  5. $5+(5/5) = 6$
>  6. $(6*6)/6 = 6$
>  7. $7-(7/7) = 6$
>  8. $8^3/8^2-8^{1/3} = 6$
>  9. $(9+9)/9^{1/2} = 6  $

and the bonus

> $(0!+ 0! + 0!)! = 6 $

For more info on the bonus take a look here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: @user477343 Uhhh probably? This was 4 years ago and looking at the time stamps only 4 comments were before my answer and none of those comments affected my answer, thanks for your concern though.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't see the time stamps, hahah; though you already had my upvote anyway :P

Answer (score 3):

I am doing this for the eights only:

$8  \ -  \ \sqrt{\sqrt{8 + 8}} \ = \ 6$

$-\sqrt{\sqrt{8 + 8}} \ + \  8 \ = \ 6$

$(\sqrt{8 + (8 - 8)!})! \ = \ 6$

$(\sqrt{(8 - 8)! + 8})! \ = \ 6$

$((\sqrt{8 + 8})!/8)! \ = \ 6$

Comment: I deleted the invalid solutions.

Comment: Another solution: `8!! / 8 / 8`

Answer (score 2):

Having heard about this many times, I decided to give it a try. These are the answers that I came up with.

$$(1+1+1)!=6$$

$$2^2+2=6$$

$$3*3-3=6$$

$$4+(4/\sqrt4)=6$$

$$(5-5)!+5=6$$

$$6*6/6=6$$

$$7-(7-7)!=6$$

$$\sqrt[3]{8}+\sqrt[3]{8}+\sqrt[3]{8}$$

$$(9+9)/(\sqrt9)=6$$

And finally,

$$(0!+0!+0!)!=6$$

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt[3]{8}$? If so, it's `$\sqrt[3]{8}$`

Comment: I mean double square roots as in fourth roots, like $\sqrt[4]{8}$, or two square roots.

Comment: Oh, you can actually do just $\sqrt{\sqrt{8}}$, or $\sqrt[4]{8}$ (`$\sqrt{\sqrt{8}}$` or `$\sqrt[4]{8}$`). $\sqrt[n]{8}$ is `$\sqrt[n]{8}`.

Answer (score 1):

For bonus one...
((0!)+(0!)+(0!))!

Answer (score 0):

2+2+2=6

(3*3)-3=6

(4/sqrt4)+4=(4/2)+4=6

(5/5)+5=6

(6+6)-6=6

7-(7/7)=6

cubrt8+cubrt8+cubrt8=2+2+2=6

9-(9/sqrt9)=9-(9/3)=9-3=6

Comment: Most of this is OK, but I think the cube root operator isn't allowed under the rules of the question.

Comment: @randal'thor: Actually, it is. The OP said that you can use `^` with any positive integer or multiplicative inverse. So you can do 8^(1/3).

Comment: @mmking despite this being old, you cant write any extra numbers based on the correct/original rules to this puzzle

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Not to split hairs but: `The ^ operator is an exception as you are permitted to supply a second argument to it which may be any positive integer or the multiplicative inverse of it.`. 1/3 is the multiplicative inverse of 3, which is an integer.

Comment: @mmking not true, you have to supply an extra number which isnt allowed, which is why you can only square root a number, not cube route it

Comment: @mast3rd3mon 3 is not an integer?

Comment: @mmking yes, it is, which is why i said you can $\sqrt{x}$ but not $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I don't follow. 3 is an integer. You are allowed to use an integer or its inverse with the power operator. Therefore ^ (1/3) power is allowed.

Comment: 3 is an integer so it _is not allowed_. you may not write any extra numbers beyond the original

Comment: @Randal'Thor you're the math guy, you explain it :)

Answer (score -1):

> $$2+2+2$$ 
>  $$3\times3-3$$ 
>  $$\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}$$ 
>  $$\frac{5}{5}+5$$ 
>   $$6\times\frac{6}{6}$$ 
>   $$7-\frac{7}{7}$$ 
>  $$\sqrt[3]{8} +\sqrt[3]{8} +\sqrt[3]{8}$$ 
>   $$\sqrt{9}\times\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{9}$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling.SE! I've cleaned up your answer a bit for you - hopefully you noticed that this question was answered a while ago and most of your answers are equivalent to the already accepted one.

Comment: The ones with the cube roots use 3s.  There can only be 8s used in that line for digits.

Answer (score -3):

$2\times 2\times 2=6$

$3\times 3-3=6$

$\frac{(4\times 4)}4=6$

$5+(\frac55)=6$

$6+6-6=6$

$7-(\frac77)=6$

$\frac{(8\times 8)}8=6$

$9-(\frac9{\sqrt{9}})=6$

Comment: 2*2*2 is 8, not 6!

Comment: Should be 2*2+2.

Comment: Or $2+2+2$. And your $4$s and $8$s are also wrong.

Comment: $8*8/8=8$, not $8*8/8=6$.

Comment: Yikes! I will not downvote now... but I may later on if this does not get fixed soon. Please fix your errors (e.g. $2\times 2\times 2 = 8\neq 6$ as @BaileyM mentioned before and $(4\times 4)\div 4=4\neq 6$ and $(8\times 8)\div 8=8\neq 6$ too. This is because of **very basic** (not necessarily simple) mathematical rules (including basic products like $4\times 4 = 16\neq 24$ and $8\times 8 = 64\neq 48$). So once again, **please fix this errors**; otherwise, this is **not an answer**, even though it attempts to answer the puzzle. I apologise for having said this... but sadly, it is true.