# 6 - the magic number (version 2)

Tags: mathematics

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/6-the-magic-number) is a question and some answer for it. Now my question is a bit outside the box. Well,  put operators between the numbers show to get the end result:

```
10   10   10 = 6
11   11   11 = 6
```

As you can see some examples in the above link, also here is an example:

```
2 + 2 + 2 = 6
```

So, what operators should I have between them for `10` and `11` ?

Comment: downvoted it because even though the puzzle is nice I think the explanation is wrong and incomplete. For example, you say you can only put operators **between** the numbers. The accepted answer doesn't have it only between the numbers. Also I think you should have said what operators are allowed. And also no mention of the use of parentheses because I think that technically isn't an operator.

Comment: @IvoBeckers sorry, I don't know english very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10.

> $(\sqrt{10-10/10})! = 6$

11.

> $\lfloor\log 11\rfloor+\lfloor\log 11\rfloor+\lfloor\log 11\rfloor=6$

Comment: Oh wait, `log11` is less than `1.5`, So, its round will be `1`, not `2`. Right?

Comment: Well, in this case $\log$ refers to the natural logarithm, i.e., $\log_e$. So $\log_e(11) = 2.39...$.

Comment: It seems to me that Carl used the natural logarithm (the one with `e`), `ln(11)`, which is approximately equal to 2.4

Comment: If you are not fine with the natural logarithm, consider this instead $(\lfloor\sqrt{11-11/11}\rfloor)! = 6$ :-)

Comment: WTF !!! Your brain is not normal :P !! Bravo ... good for you

Answer (score 3):

For all integers $n > 1$, we can write

$$\frac{\log \left( \log(n) / \log \left( √√√√√\sqrt{n} \right) \right)}{\log(\lceil √√\dots\sqrt{n} \rceil )}=6$$

First, we use the fact that $$\log(n) / \log(√√√√√\sqrt{n}) =64.$$

To get a "free" $2$, we repeatedly take the square root of our number $n$: we know that for all $n > 1$, $1 < \sqrt{n} < n$, so eventually we approach $1$ from above, but never reach it. Then, we take the ceiling of this value, and get $\lceil 1+\varepsilon \rceil = 2$.

Then, we simply calculate $\log(64) / \log(2) = 6$.