# Make N N N equal to 6 where N is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Using standard mathematical symbols, (i.e. no other letters or numbers), make the following true:

```
0 0 0 = 6
1 1 1 = 6
2 2 2 = 6
3 3 3 = 6
4 4 4 = 6
5 5 5 = 6
6 6 6 = 6
7 7 7 = 6
8 8 8 = 6
9 9 9 = 6
```

As a freebie, I will give the easiest away, `2 + 2 + 2 = 6`

All numbers are base 10...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [6, the magic number](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/6-the-magic-number) - I should've known it was asked before.

Comment: Drat, I was completely unaware... I tried every possible combination of searches to verify the possibility of a duplicate and came up with nothing... @Glorfindel I've given you a vote up to help ease the pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> (0! + 0! + 0!)! = 6
>  (1 + 1 + 1)! = 6
>  2^2 + 2 = 6
>  3 * 3 - 3 = 6
>  √4 + √4 + √4 = 6
>  5 + 5 / 5 = 6
>  6 + 6 - 6 = 6
>  7 - 7 / 7 = 6
>  8 - √(√(8 + 8)) = 6
>  √9 * √9 - √9 = 6
>
>  (for those of you unfamiliar with the !, it's the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial))

Comment: Definitely well thought out. I pretty much had the same answers when I was first presented with this puzzle a while back. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Some variations:

> (0! + 0! + 0!)! = 6
>  (1 + 1 + 1)! = 6
>  2 + 2 + 2 = 6
>  3! - 3! + 3!= 6
>  √4 + √4 + √4 = 6
>  5 / 5 + 5 = 6
>  6 + 6 - 6 = 6
>  7 - 7 / 7 = 6
>  8 - √(√(8 + 8)) = 6
>  √9 * √9 - √9 = 6

And an other minimalist solution (for computer folks)

> 0 + 0 + 0 != 6
>  1 + 1 + 1 != 6
>  2 + 2 - 2 != 6
>  3 + 3 + 3 != 6
>  4 + 4 + 4 != 6
>  5 + 5 + 5 != 6
>  6 + 6 + 6 != 6
>  7 + 7 + 7 != 6
>  8 + 8 + 8 != 6
>  9 + 9 + 9 != 6

Comment: If you add two spaces after each spoilered line, the formatting will work as intended.

Comment: I hadn't considered `3! - 3! + 3!`, nice variation!

Comment: ok thx ! neewbee here:)